# Why are subclasses' private variables kept when stored in a superclass type variable?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I must have missed something basic in inheritance since it doesn't make sense to me.

Given these two classes:

```
class Person
{
   private String name;
}

class Student extends Person
{
   private String degree;
}
```

Why is it possible to create a new `Student` object, store it in a `Person` type variable and still be able to keep the variable `String degree` and have access to it?

```
Person p = new Student("John", "Master's");
```

I thought that this is possible to use the above initialization because `p` will not have any variable other than `name`, since a `Person` variable can't contain a `degree` variable, and so it's legal - but when you do that, `degree` doesn't exist in `p`.

That's what I thought the reason was behind the fact that the opposite is illegal
(`Student s = new Person("John");`) - because then `s` will not have its other variable (`degree`) initialized.

Comment: I do not see the question. There is one, but you answer it by yourself? You can call a student "person", but you can not call all persons "student". Every student knows about his degrees, even if you call them person. But in general, a person does not have a degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable with a type of reference to a supertype can hold a reference to an instance of a subtype. Assigning the subtype instance to the variable does *not* change the instance in any way; it just broadens the type of reference. All the instance data is still there, and can be retrieved by a down-cast. That is,

```
Student s = new Student("John", "Master's");
Person p = s; // no cast needed for a widening conversion
```

is exactly the same as:

```
Person p = new Student("John", "Master's");
Student s = (Student) p; // cast required for a narrowing conversion
```

**EDIT** Perhaps this will help clarify things.
Suppose there was a second subclass of `Person`:

```
class Teacher extends Person
{
    private String department;
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
Person p = new Teacher("Fred", "Physics");
Teacher t = (Teacher) p;
```

But if you later tried to do this:

```
p = new Teacher("Fred", "Physics");
Student s = (Student) p; // Error!
```

you'll get a [`ClassCastException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) because at that point in the program, `p` is now a reference to an object (an instance of `Teacher`) that is not a `Student`.

Here's an analogy. In English, you might say, "I have a pet animal". This says nothing about the type of animal. (You cannot know whether the pet barks, for instance.) On the other hand, if you say, "I have a pet dog", then it makes sense to ask whether it barks at strangers. The key point is: *calling your pet an animal doesn't change the fact that it is (or is not) a dog*. Exactly the same thing is going on with Java references—using a more general (e.g., base class) reference type to store the object reference does not change the nature of the object itself. You lose *knowledge* of the details of the object, but those details are still there.

To repeat the point I made in my comment: you never assign objects to variables in Java; you only assign *references* to objects. Or, to put it another way, none of your variables are objects.

Comment: So even though it looks (at least to me) as if the "lowest" subclass contains the most variables because it has all the variables the classes "above it" contain and its own - it's actually the base class that has all of the variables? It's confusing, because thinking of it as an **is-a** relationship doesn't make much sense in practice. It looks like the word **extends** makes sense though.

Comment: @tempy - You are right that the lowest class has the most variables. A base class object only has the variables declared in the base class. However, don't confuse a reference to an instance with the instance itself. Assigning an object reference to a base class variable does not make the object a base class object.

Comment: It's really confusing me because I'm not used to it yet... By looking at the examples you included, it looks like I really need to think about it as `x is y but y is not x`, but I have to admit it still looks weird when I read the code.

Comment: @tempy - I expanded my answer; perhaps it will help a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes more sense now; one thing though - What happens when you don't narrow the type by casting (e.g leaving `Person p = new Student("John", "Master's");` as is)? Is the `degree`inaccessible?

Comment: @tempy - Any data defined by the subclass will be inaccessible until you narrow the reference type (unless you use reflection, which is an entirely different topic).

Answer (score 0):

Variables don't *hold* objects.  Variables hold *references*, which *identify* objects.  If one has a list of automotive vehicle identification numbers (VIN in the US), the list itself may contain numbers for cars of many different sorts; from the perspective of the list, each number is known to identify a Vehicle, but one number might identify FordFocus, another a ToyotaPrius, another a ChevroletSebringConvertible, etc.  If one writes the number of a ChevroletSebringConvertible on the list, the list would have no idea that it was a convertible, and so one couldn't say "Raise the top on the fifth car on the list" without first establishing that the car identified by the fifth VIN had a convertible top.  The top wouldn't be something that came into existence when the car was identified as a convertible; the top and its state (raised or lowered) would continue to exist regardless of who knew about them.